# Update jQuery Datatables cell with geocoded address

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable which is displaying my data (see below). You will notice the last column is address and the row data simply says loading.

[image: Table]

I want to get the address from the google maps api using the longitude and latitude in the data.

I know getting the address can take some time and if 3000 results are returned it will take a long time which is why I have not passed the pre geocoded address in the data.

Once the table data is displayed can i start geocoding the lat/lngs for each row and update the address column as each one is completed?

I am also using the GMAP3 jQuery plugin for google maps so i can get the address like this:

```
        // get address
        $("#map").gmap3({
          action: 'getAddress',
          latLng: [lati, longi],
          callback: function (results) {
            content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'No Address';
          } // end callback

        });
```

**UPDATE**

Nearly done it :)
The classes are added to lat,long and address ok and i am receiving the geocoded addresses into the console. All i need to do is get the address into the correct row in the table. How will i do that?

My code
      var historyArray = window.opener.historyArray;

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            //$('#dynamic').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="report"></table>' );
            $('#report').dataTable( {
                "aaData": historyArray,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "User" },
                    { "mDataProp": "Timestamp" },
                    { "mDataProp": "Latitude" },
                    { "mDataProp": "Longitude" },
                    { "mDataProp": "Address" }
                ],
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
                "oTableTools": {
                            "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                            "aButtons": ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                                      },
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    getAdresses();
                }
            } );    

$("#report td:nth-child(3)").addClass("lat");
$("#report td:nth-child(4)").addClass("lng");
$("#report td:nth-child(5)").addClass("addi");
} );

 function getAdresses() {
   $.each(historyArray, function (index,data) {
    // get address
    var map = window.opener.document.getElementById('dispatcher');
    $(map).gmap3({
      action: 'getAddress',
      latLng: [data.Latitude, data.Longitude],
      callback: function (results) {
        content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'No Address';
        console.log(content);
      } // end callback

    });
   });
 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Hi, updated code.
because i have added $(this).html(content); in the callback of the gmap3 it is not updating the 'addi' cell, how can i fix?

```
 function getAdresses() {
   $(".addi").each(function () {
     var lat = $(this).siblings(".lat").html().toString();
     var lng = $(this).siblings(".lng").html().toString();
      // get address
      $(map).gmap3({
        action: 'getAddress',
        latLng: [lat, lng],
        callback: function (results) {
          content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'No Address';
          $(this).html(content);
        } // end callback

      });
   });
 }
```

**Final Update**
To add to the solution kindly given.
I found that when i exported the data to CSV , Excel etc the address data was not updated.

I modified the code to this.

```
       myTable = $('#report').dataTable({
     "aaData": historyArray,
     "aoColumns": [{
       "mDataProp": "User"
     }, {
       "mDataProp": "Timestamp"
     }, {
       "mDataProp": "Latitude"
     }, {
       "mDataProp": "Longitude"
     }, {
       "mDataProp": "Address"
     }],
     "bPaginate": false,
     "bJQueryUI": true,
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
     "oTableTools": {
       "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
       "aButtons": ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf"]
     },
     "fnInitComplete": function () {
       addClasses();
     }
   });
   window.setTimeout(function () {
     getAdresses();
   }, 1000);
 });

 function addClasses() {
   $("#report td:nth-child(3)").addClass("lat");
   $("#report td:nth-child(4)").addClass("lng");
   $("#report td:nth-child(5)").addClass("addi");
 }

 function getAdresses() {
   $(".addi").each(function () {
     var lat = $(this).siblings(".lat").html().toString();
     var lng = $(this).siblings(".lng").html().toString();
     var addi = $(this);
     $(addi).html("Reverse geocoding..");
     var aPos = myTable.fnGetPosition(this);

     // get address
     $('#hidden').gmap3({
       action: 'getAddress',
       latLng: [lat, lng],
       callback: function (results) {
         content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'No Address';
         myTable.fnUpdate(content, aPos[0], 4);
       } // end callback

     });
   });
 }
```

Now the data is truly updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly:

You can add a class to the final column through jQuery like this:

`$("#table td:nth-child(5)").addClass("someClass");`

Then you can create a function that runs *after* the table is initialized:

```
//Part of the datatable initialization
"fnInitComplete": function () {
    myAwesomeFunction();
}
```

In that function you can just do `.each()` based on class and grab the siblings (lat and long) pass those to the api and do `.html()` with the result to replace the loading text.
I hope this makes sense. If not let me know :)

//EDIT//

To grab the siblings:
First give them a class

`$("#table td:nth-child(3)").addClass("lat");`

`$("#table td:nth-child(4)").addClass("long");`

Just remember you have to apply all these styles after datatable is initialized.

then you can:

```
var lat = $(this).siblings(".lat").html().toString();
var long = $(this).siblings(".long").html().toString();
```

/////////////
///EDIT 2 ///
/////////////

First move this code:

```
$("#report td:nth-child(3)").addClass("lat");
$("#report td:nth-child(4)").addClass("lng");
$("#report td:nth-child(5)").addClass("addi");
```

To a function like this:

```
$("#report").on("draw", function() {
   addClasses();
});

function addClasses() {
    $("#report td:nth-child(3)").addClass("lat");
    $("#report td:nth-child(4)").addClass("lng");
    $("#report td:nth-child(5)").addClass("addi");
}
```

And add the `addClasses()` function to the `fnInitcomplete` *before* `getAddresses()`

This way the classes will be applied/reapplied if you change page or sort or w/e other change to the table happens.

I'm not sure how the API for geo stuff works but in order to grab the long latt i would do something like this:

```
    $(".addi").each(function () {
        var lat = $(this).siblings(".lat").html().toString();
        var lng = $(this).siblings(".lng").html().toString();
        // Now pass these parameters to the geocode function and store the result in some var
        //In this case lets call it result
        //Now just replace the loading with the result:
        $(this).html(result);
    });
```

Put the above code in the `getAddresses()` function and it should give you the results.

Let me know if it this is sufficient and if it works fine ;)

Comment: Hi, yes I understand and will give it a go, I will probably need more help on how to grab the siblings.

Comment: @ Iro ok i have done that thanks. See my Update 2 i have one more problem to overcome :) thanks for your help

Comment: Ok i have fixed by doing var addi = $(this); then $(addi).html(content);, not sure if that's the nicest way?

Comment: Probably not, but I don't understand why the original didn't work. I have to check that.